# Silverlight mouse button up outside control

Tags: silverlight, events, mouse

I have a made a simple UserControl that allows a user to drag a button around and drop it. It uses MouseLeftButtonDown and MouseLeftButtonUp to start and stop dragging.

The problem is, however, that MouseLeftButtonUp is only triggered when the mouse is actualy on my UserControl.

How can I catch 'global' mouse events on this UserControl?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the CaptureMouse method (Silverlight 3+) [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.capturemouse%28v=VS.95%29.aspx).